# How do I write the Criteria in Query Design to equal last month's data?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've looked on a couple different forums and I'm unable to find what I need they all have it listed in SQL View, and that is NOT what I want. I would like to do this in the Query Design as it is much easier for me.

I simply would like to make a query to display certain parameters of the database I maintain. And those parameters would equal last month's data.

I previously was able to successfully make a query displaying all information for the past year but can't figure out how to display just this past months.

The past year Criteria:

```
>DateAdd("yyyy",-1,Date())
```

Since that worked I tried doing this but it would not work for me:

```
>DateAdd("mmmm",-1,Date())
```

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just not seeing here. Any help or recommendations are welcome.

Referencing the link provided by Fionnuala I have come up with

```
>DateAdd("m',-30,Date())
```

The problem being is that it queries all results for the past 30 days from Today's date. I wish to display only data from October ! While this can be done easily. I don't wish to manually go in this query every month and change certain parameters. I would like it to be automatic so or next month December I click on the query and it displays all 30 days of November's data. And there is no manual process of going back in and changing any of the criteria.

Comment: Try reading about DateAdd : http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php

Comment: It was as simple as eliminating three of the "m's" in the interval syntax. I knew it would be something simple just needed a second set of eyes. If you'd like you can post as an answer and I'll accept so you can get points. Thanks Fionnuala !

Comment: Actually I was a bit hasty on this one. I'll revise the above question from the link that you provided on what's happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Query Designer you can use a `Criteria:` like this

```
>=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,1) And <DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)
```

[image: QueryDesign.png]

The corresponding SQL statement is

```sql
SELECT Donations.*
FROM Donations
WHERE (((Donations.DonationDate)>=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,1) 
    And (Donations.DonationDate)<DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)));
```

If it was run on November 18, 2014 then it would effectively be

```sql
SELECT Donations.*
FROM Donations
WHERE (((Donations.DonationDate)>=DateSerial(2014,10,1) 
    And (Donations.DonationDate)<DateSerial(2014,11,1)));
```

Notes:

1. This query should be [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and take advantage of an index on the date field (if one exists).
2. In case anyone is concerned about "month wrap-around", the `DateSerial()` function takes care of that for us. If the query was run in January 2015 then the first WHERE condition would indeed be `... >=DateSerial(2015,0,1)` but that's okay because it returns `2014-12-01`.

Comment: Once again you've helped me out Gord ! It works I don't fully understand the logic behind it though.